# I am Trying to execute this code and near option==4 it shows an error

Tags: python, mysql

I am doing a project of connecting python and mysql
near option == 4
when i run the code
it shows error

input:

```
    
import sys
import mysql.connector as sql
conn=sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='1Chirumamilla$',database='medical_store')
c1=conn.cursor()
if conn.is_connected:
    print("                                                       WELCOME TO SAI MEDICAL STORE             ")
    print("1. Login")
    print()
    option=int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    if option==1:
        print()
        user=input('User Name : ')
        user=user.upper()
        c1.execute("select * from account_details where User_Name like '" + user + "'")
        datas=c1.fetchall()
        for i in datas:
            value_1=i[0]
            value_2=i[1]
            if user==value_1:
                password=input('Password : ')
                password=password.upper()
                if password!=value_2:
                    print("INVALID PASSWORD")
                    print("RUN THE PROGRAM AGAIN")
                    sys.exit()
                elif password==value_2:
                    print()
                    print('Login successful')
                    print()
                    def med():
                    
                                print("SELECT THE OPTION")
                                print()
                                print("1.Customer's Account")
                                print("2.Medicine Cost")
                                print("3.Search Medicine Stock")
                                print("4.Search Customer")
                                print("5.Bill")
                                print("6.Add Medicines")
                                print("7.Search Employee Details")
                                print("8.Add or Delete Employee Details")
                                print()
                                option=int(input("Enter an option:"))
                                if option==1:
                                                account_number=int(input("Enter customer's acct_number:"))
                                                patient_name=input("Enter customer's name:")
                                                age=int(input("Enter customer's age:"))
                                                address=input("Enter customer's address:")
                                                phone_number=int(input("Enter customer's mobile number:"))
                                                balance_amount=float(input("Enter Amount Paid:"))
                                                x="insert into customers_details values("+str(account_number)+",'"+patient_name+"',"+str(age)+",'"+address+"',"+str(phone_number)+","+str(balance_amount)+")"
                                                c1.execute(x)
                                                print("Account created")
                                                conn.commit()
                                if option==2:
                                    a=input("Enter the Medicine Name to show Price : ").upper()
                                    f=int(input("Enter the Quantity : "))
                                    c1.execute("select medicine_name,total_cost from medicines_details where medicine_name like '" + a + "'")
                                    b=c1.fetchall()
                                    for x in b:
                                        print("Medicine Name : ",x[0])
                                        print("Medicine Cost : ",x[1]*f)
                                if option==3:
                                    Med=input("Enter Medicine name to search : ").upper().strip()
                                    c1.execute("select  medicine_name from medicines_details; " )
                                    b = [i[0] for i in c1.fetchall()]
                                    if Med in b :
                                        print("Medicine is in stock")
                                    else:
                                        print("Medicine out of stock")
                                if option==4:
                                    accnum=int(input("Enter the Customer's Account Number :"))
                                    print("Customer Account Number, Customer name, Phone Numbers Are Given Below")
                                    print()
                                    c1.execute("select account_number, patient_name, phone_number from customers_details where account_number like "+str(accnum)+"")
                                    c=c1.fetchall()
                                    b = [i[0] for i in c1.fetchall()]
                                    if b == accnum:
                                        for x in c:
                                            print("Account Number : " ,x[0])
                                            print("Name : ",x[1])
                                            print("Mobile Number : ",x[2])
                                            print()
                                        
                                    else:
                                        print("Customer Details Dont exist")
                                        print("Create A New Account")
                                    
                                        
                                if option==5:
                                        patient_name=input("enter the patient_name :")
                                        no=int(input('enter the number of medicine:'))
                                        print('customer name:',patient_name)
                                        for i in range (no):
                                            med_name=input('enter medicine name : ')
                                            c1.execute("select medicine_code,gst,sgst,total_cost from medicines_details where medicine_name like '" + str(med_name) +"'" )
                                            data=c1.fetchall()
                                            for row in data:
                                                print('medicine_code of',med_name,':',row[0])
                                                print('gst of',med_name,':',row[1])
                                                print('sgst of',med_name,':',row[2])
                                                print('cost_per_item of',med_name,':',row[3])
                                                conn.commit()
                                                account_number=input('enter account_number:')
                                                c1.execute("select balance_amount from customers_details where account_number like'"+str(account_number)+"'")
                                                datas=c1.fetchall()
                                                datas=list(datas[0])
                                                datas=datas[0]
                                                print(datas)
                                                conn.commit()
                                                print("rows affected:",c1.rowcount)
                                                conn.commit()
                                                quantity=int(input("enter the quantity:"))
                                                total_amount=row[3]*quantity
                                                print("total_amount of",med_name,':',total_amount)
                                                v_sql_insert="insert into SS_bill (medicine_name,medicine_code,gst,sgst,cost_per_item,quantity,amount_paid,amount_to_be_paid)values('{}',{},{},{},{},{},{},{})".format(med_name,row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],quantity,datas,total_amount)
                                                c1.execute(v_sql_insert)
                                                conn.commit()
                                                print("Records added")
                                if option == 6:
                                    mednam=input("Enter the Name of the Medicine : ").upper()
                                    medcod=int(input("Enter the 6 digit code : "))
                                    medgst=float(input("Enter the GST on the Medicine : "))
                                    sgmed=float(input("Enter the SGST on the Medicine : "))
                                    medcos=float(input("Enter the price of the Medicine : "))
                                    x="insert into medicines_details values('"+ mednam +"',"+ str(medcod) +","+ str(medgst) +","+ str(sgmed) +","+ str(medcos) +")"
                                    c1.execute(x)
                                    print("Medicine Added")
                                    conn.commit()
                                    
                                if option == 7:
                                    empid = int(input("Enter the Employee Id : "))
                                    x="select employee_name, employee_id, designation, date_of_joining, salary from employees_details where employee_id like '"+ str(empid) +"'"
                                    c1.execute(x)
                                    c=c1.fetchall()
                                    for x in c:
                                        print("Employee Name : ",x[0] )
                                        print("Customer Id : ",x[1])
                                        print("Designation : ",x[2])
                                        print("Year of Joining : ",x[3])
                                        print("Salary : ",x[4])
                                        
                                            
                                if option == 8:
                                    print("1.Add Employee")
                                    print("2.Remove Employee")
                                    print()
                                    c=int(input("Choose the option to continue : "))
                                    if c == 2:
                                        a=input("Enter the Employee Id of the employee to remove : ")
                                        x="delete from employees_details where employee_id like '"+ str(a) +"'"
                                        c1.execute(x)
                                        conn.commit()
                                        print("Employee Removed")
                                    if c == 1:
                                        b=input("Enter the Employee Name to add : ")
                                        e=int(input("Enter the Employee ID : "))
                                        f=input("Enter the designation of the employee : ")
                                        g=input("Enter the year of joining of the employee : ")
                                        i=int(input("Enter the Salary of the Employee : "))
                                        y="insert into employees_details values ('" +b+ "',"+str(e)+", '" +f+ "',"+str(g)+","+str(i)+")"
                                        c1.execute(y)
                                        conn.commit()
                                        print("Employee Added")

                                restart=input("Do you want to continue? (YES/NO)").upper()
                                if restart == "YES":
                                    med()
                                elif restart == "NO":
                                    print("Thank You Visit Again")
                                    sys.exit()
med()
```

if put accnum = 9989 which exists in the mysql table but when i run the code it shows the value is not present

output:

```
Enter the Customer's Account Number :9989
Customer Account Number, Customer name, Phone Numbers Are Given Below

Customer Details Dont exist
Create A New Account
```

Comment: Could you post the full error you are getting? It will tell you exactly where is your error and what is it.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you probably want `where User_Name = '" + user + "'"` not `where User_Name like '" + user + "'"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get `b==accnum` evaluated to true as `b` is a list (like [9989,9989,..] in this case) while `accnum` is just a integer variable.
Just replace

```
if b==accnum:
```

with

```
if len(c)>0:
```

It will check if list contains any number of records with given account number, otherwise list will be empty with size zero.